# Dictionary as private field in Script# class

Tags: c#, script#

I have the following class in script# 0.7.5:

```
[ScriptNamespace("Scripts")]
public class MyClass 
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> stageMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public PortfolioOptimisationOverlord()
    {
        stageMapping["first"] = "http://www.me.com/mike";
        stageMapping["second"] = "http://www.me.com/terry";
        stageMapping["third"] = "http://www.me.com/billy";
        stageMapping["fourth"] = "http://www.me.com/bobby";
        stageMapping["fifth"] = "http://www.me.com/richard";
    }
}
```

unfortunately when compiled it doesn't produce a prototype class so fails saying that it can't access `this`.

If I make a private field of type `int` it seems to work, but not with dictionarys or lists.

--EDIT--

here's some more information:
The javascript produced by this is:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Scripts.PortfolioOptimisationOverlord

Scripts.PortfolioOptimisationOverlord = function Scripts_PortfolioOptimisationOverlord() {
    /// <field name="_stageMapping" type="Object">
    /// </field>
    this._stageMapping = {};
    this._stageMapping['first'] = 'http://www.me.com/mike';
    this._stageMapping['second'] = 'http://www.me.com/terry';
    this._stageMapping['third'] = 'http://www.me.com/billy';
    this._stageMapping['fourth'] = 'http://www.me.com/bobby';
    this._stageMapping['fifth'] = 'http://www.me.com/richard';
}
```

If I add an `int` private field called `intField`:

```
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Scripts.PortfolioOptimisationOverlord

Scripts.PortfolioOptimisationOverlord = function Scripts_PortfolioOptimisationOverlord() {
    /// <field name="_stageMapping" type="Object">
    /// </field>
    /// <field name="_intField" type="Number" integer="true">
    /// </field>
    this._stageMapping = {};
    this._stageMapping['first'] = 'http://www.me.com/mike';
    this._stageMapping['second'] = 'http://www.me.com/terry';
    this._stageMapping['third'] = 'http://www.me.com/billy';
    this._stageMapping['fourth'] = 'http://www.me.com/bobby';
    this._stageMapping['fifth'] = 'http://www.me.com/richard';
}
Scripts.PortfolioOptimisationOverlord.prototype = {
    _intField: 0
}
```

as you can see the only change is the addition of a type with `.prototype` on the end.

it fails on construction.

Comment: This does not look like javascript

Comment: Can you post some more code? What's the generated Javascript like. Where does it fail saying it can't access this? Is it simply when you try to create an instance of this class?

Comment: And btw, S# doesn't produce prototypes. I think in 0.7.5 it produces the module pattern just like 0.8 (where it also does the AMD pattern).

Comment: Also, you might want to try 0.8. Here's a doc on getting started: https://github.com/theoutlander/scriptsharp/wiki/Using-the-development-branch

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your feedback, I've clarified the question above. We can't move to 0.8 as we are constrained to work in XP or Server 2013 which can't run VS 2012 which is a prerequisite. Any further OSes are not supported by our corporate network and there's no way around it (believe me, I've tried!) so we'll have to wait until the release before we can move.

Comment: I think I see what you're talking about. I would need to see the entire code to be able to tell what's going on. Can you post the files somewhere or on jsfiddle? My guess is that the class instantiation order could be changed with the introduction of the integer. What I need to see is where is the call to create a (new PortfolioOptimisationOverlord()) being made? Is it before the class is defined in the first scenario? Hope you can move to 0.8 sometime soon. It does work with VS 2012/2013 Express.

Comment: Btw, the reason I need to see more code is because I tried this in JSFiddle and it seems to work fine (with a small mod - removing "Scripts." since I don't have that lib). http://jsfiddle.net/theoutlander/RTmtt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that 0.8 was the answer. Thanks to all who offered help.